# Chat Transcript as RSS feed

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, chat, irc

I was just wondering if there are plans to make the transcripts available through an RSS feed.

I could imagine it being filtered by starred posts. 
It could make a great daily/weekly digest to catch up with your chosen community.

Just my two cents.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You mean, a bit like the RSS feed per room for starred posts?

`http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/feeds/rooms/starred/[room number]`

it is linked on the page... under "starred" ;p

Comment: Ah I see it now. I'm so used to nabbing RSS feeds from the address bar ;).

It might be an idea to add these queues on the transcript page itself, too.
Thanks Marc

Comment: @Jaspio OK; will look at adding the links to the head

Comment: is there a way to take an RSS feed on all posts? transcript or live, don't know nor care - but say to be able to put the chat as RSS feed to be served say in a private/corp slack channel

Comment: @NasBanov If you have a question, please ask it separately instead of hijacking this thread

Comment: @NasBanov our new "teams" product (and "enterprise" too, IIRC) has full slack support

Comment: @JohnLocke one part of me wants to say "no need to bump an 18-month old comment", but another part of me wants to say "wow! yes, we can do that now, but we couldn't at the time"

Comment: @MarcGravell Telling them to ask about something they may already know the answer to by now is better than them wondering why no one is answering them. It's better than having them find related posts to ask the question on and cluttering up the comments.